# Can I make a custom orientation lock button?

Tags: iphone, locking, orientation

So I feel that the code behind setting up a custom in-app orientation lock will not be terribly difficult. You may be asking why I would want to have one?

The iPad's switch just got changed to the mute switch, and the iOS lock feature is hardly conveniently placed. Also, users of older devices that don't support the multi-task bar are out of luck.

**My Question**
Does anybody know of there is anything that Apple would have against me setting up a trivial little orientation lock system in the toolbar of my reading app? Anything as far as developer agreements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Economist iPhone app has an orientation lock in the toolbar, and their app is happily living in the App Store.  That's just one example, but it seems that Apple is fine with this feature.